# Simple taking too long

Tags: performance, google-bigquery

Query is as simmple as:

SELECT * from [tablename] where some_timestamp_type > TIMESTAMP("2017-05-01") [our-tracker-169919:bquijob_50035ae4_15cada135bb]

Table has ~11M rows, and is take 30+ minutes.

I realize that particular query does some non-trivial output, but even tiny-output queries over the table taking 30+ minutes:

example: our-tracker-169919:bquijob_50035ae4_15cada135bb

Seems off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries over CSV files on Google Drive will generally be much slower than if you load the data into BigQuery and then query it. Another option, which will probably be better than CSV but not as fast as BigQuery's managed storage, is to query Avro files on Google Drive.

Can you try loading your data into BigQuery and then trying your query again?

Comment: oh absolutely, I had just assumed it imported the data from Google Drive into its own intermediate format for future querying.

Will def give this a shot and update.

Comment: Waaaaay faster and way more compressed to boot.  Got charged for 130MB down from 2GB for exact same dataset/query.  Huge thanks.